# Weasyprint HTML to PDF huge gap in right margin

Tags: python, css, django, pdf, weasyprint

I'm using Weasyprint to print an HTML template to PDF, and I keep getting a gap of 10cm on the right side.

I'm using @page:(size:letter;) as only page attribute.

I've tried setting the page size manually, but I still keep getting a huge space to the right of all the pages.

Any thoughts on what could be the problem?

Comment: Please share the HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It was a CSS problem. The class used to style the body was not at the beginning of the css file and that caused erratic behavior with other styles declared before it.